# Moving expenses: dog kennel

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, moving

I had to kennel my dogs while moving. Is this deductible as a moving expense (temporary storage of household items)?

Comment: Can we assume that the move does qualify as deductible, and this is just a question about this one expense?

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I am not a tax professional. Please don't rely on this answer in lieu of professional advice.

Please see [IRS Publication 521](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p521/ar02.html#en_US_2010_publink1000203491) (emphasis added):

> [Y]ou can deduct the reasonable expenses of: [...]
>
> - Traveling (including **lodging** but not meals) to your new home.
>
> [...]
>
> You can deduct the cost of **packing**, **crating**, and transporting your household goods and personal effects and those of the members of your household from your former home to your new home.
>
> [...]
>
> You can deduct the cost of shipping your car and your **household pets** to your new home.

While it doesn't specifically mention temporarily housing your dogs in a kennel, I would see this as a deductible expense.

Of course, this assumes your moving expenses are deductible in general: [*Who Can Deduct Moving Expenses*](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p521/ar02.html#en_US_2010_publink1000203444).